# Displaying time difference with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using a datepicker to choose dates, I want to calculate difference between dates choosen & then alert the difference.I'm not able see the code work

HTML datepicker

```
<input type="date" size="8" name="advDurFrom" />
<input type="date" size="8" name="advDurTo"/>
```

Javascript

```
   $('input[name=advDurFrom]').click(function() {
    var x=$('input[name=advDurFrom]').val();
    var date1 = new Date(x);
    });
        $('input[name=advDurTo]').click(function() {
        var y=$('input[name=advDurTo]').val();
    var date2 = new Date(y);
    });
    $('input[name=advDurTo]').focusout(function() {
    var diffDays = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime(); 
    alert(diffDays);
    });
```

Comment: What it is giving for u

Comment: nothing, the code isn't working

Comment: `getTime` returns milliseconds. What's your date format?

Comment: replace focusout() by blur(). Also make date1 and date2 global by removing var. ie 'var date1' to 'date1'...

Comment: @elclanrs , its 05/5/2013

Comment: instead of `var diffDays` write `var diff = new Date();
diff.setTime(date2.getTime()-date1.getTime() );`

Comment: @ankitpatel , it doesn't work

Comment: Could you post a live fiddle?

Comment: @ankitpatel , it alerts "Nan" now

Comment: @elclanrs http://jsfiddle.net/rCtcL/

Comment: @user210068 check out the given ans. And let me know if you have any trouble.

Comment: @user210068 you forgot to include jquery in your fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html:

```
<input type="date" name="startdate">
<input type="date" name="enddate">
<button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
<h2 id="result"></h2>
```

Script:

```
var startdateInput = document.querySelector('input[name="startdate"]'),
    enddateInput = document.querySelector('input[name="enddate"]'),
    calculateButton = document.getElementById('calculate'),
    resultElement = document.getElementById('result');

calculateButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    if( startdateInput.value && enddateInput.value ) {
        result.textContent = new Date(enddateInput.value) - new Date(startdateInput.value);
    }    
});
```

Or see the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zJTfM/

The result is the number of milliseconds between the start and end date.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name=advDurFrom]').live('change', function(e) {
    var x=$(this).datepicker( "getDate" );
    date1 = x.getTime();
});
$('input[name=advDurTo]').live('change', function(e) {
    var y=$(this).datepicker( "getDate" );
    date2 = y.getTime();
});
$('input[name=advDurTo]').live('blur', function(e) {
    if(date2 && date1){
        var diffDays = date2 - date1 ; 
        alert(diffDays);
    } else {
        alert("date is not selected.")
    } 
});
```

Comment: It doesn't alert anything now

Comment: @user210068 try now please

Comment: there i made mistake, i forgot to replace focusout() with blur().

Comment: Now it looks perfect, try it

Answer (score 0):

In my project I use this function to calculate difference day between 2 date,I modify some for you. [see demo in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/james_nguyen/RfXYe/)

HTML:

```
<input type="text" size="8" name="advDurFrom" />
<input type="text" size="8" name="advDurTo"/>
difference days: <span class="diff"><span>
```

JS:

```
function CalendarDays(startDate, endDate) {
    if (endDate < startDate)
        return 0;

    // Calculate days between dates
    var millisecondsPerDay = 86400 * 1000; // Day in milliseconds
    startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 1); // Start just after midnight
    endDate.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999); // End just before midnight
    var diff = endDate - startDate; // Milliseconds between datetime objects
    var days = Math.round(diff / millisecondsPerDay);

    return days;
}
function common_getDateFromUI(str) {
    var arr = str.split("/");
    var returnDate = new Date(arr[2], arr[1] - 1, arr[0], 0, 0, 0, 0);
    return returnDate;
}
$().ready(function(){
    $('input[name="advDurFrom"],input[name="advDurTo"]').datepicker( {
        showOn : "both",
        dateFormat : "dd/mm/yy",
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        buttonImageOnly : true,
        onSelect : function(dateText, inst) {    
                var day1 =  common_getDateFromUI($('input[name="advDurFrom"]').val());      
                var day2 =  common_getDateFromUI($('input[name="advDurTo"]').val());    
                $(".diff").html(CalendarDays(day1,day2));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare the variable globally. Try this code. This is working perfectly for me.

```
var date1 = "";
var date2 = "";

$('#advDurFrom').click(function () {
    var x = $(this).val();
    date1 = new Date(x);
});
$('#advDurTo').click(function () {
    var y = $(this).val();
    date2 = new Date(y);
});
$('#advDurTo').focusout(function () {
    var diffDays = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    alert(diffDays);
});
```

And Change the HTML to

```
 <input type="date" size="8" id="advDurFrom" />
 <input type="date" size="8" id="advDurTo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

getTime returns millisecond, you just need to convert into the correct unit. Here an example with days difference. Also use blur event not click or you will end up assigning the value before the user actually inputs it

```
var isOK = false;
var isOK2 = false;
$('input[name=advDurFrom]').blur(function () {
    var x = $('input[name=advDurFrom]').val();
    try {
        date1 = new Date(x);
        isOK = !isNaN(date1);
    } catch (e) {
        isOK = false;
    }
    printDiff();
});
$('input[name=advDurTo]').blur(function () {
    var y = $('input[name=advDurTo]').val();
    try {
        date2 = new Date(y);
        isOK2 = !isNaN(date2);
    } catch (e) {
        isOK2 = false;
    }
    printDiff();
});

function printDiff(){
    if (isOK && isOK2) {
        var one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        var diff = Math.ceil((date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()) / (one_day));
        console.log(diff + ' days');
    }
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/tLPs9/)

Comment: @user210068 oh i found out, you use click event to retrieve the value before it is set. just use blur everywhere it should be OK with a verification that it's not NaN