# How to add time into date instance using JQuery and get hours by Subtracting Two dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add time into date and want to get hours by subtracting EndDate and StartDate..Following is my try.Please help me

```
var selectedStartDate;
        var selectedEndDate;
        $("#StartDate").change(function () {
            selectedStartDate = $('#StartDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }).val();
            alert(selectedStartDate);
        });
        $("#EndDate").change(function () {
            debugger;
            selectedEndDate = $('#EndDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }).val();
            alert(selectedEndDate);
            selectedEndDate = selectedEndDate + ' ' + '12:00:00 AM';
            selectedStartDate = selectedStartDate + ' ' + '10:00:00 AM';
            var timeDiff = Math.abs(selectedEndDate- selectedStartDate);

            alert(timeDiff);
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying time difference with javascript/jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829299/displaying-time-difference-with-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are. I refactored the code, I think we don't need the time, else should use datetimepicker instead of datepicker:

```js
var selectedStartDate;
var selectedEndDate;
$("#StartDate").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  onSelect: onSelect
});
$("#EndDate").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  onSelect: onSelect
});

function onSelect(dateText, inst) {
  selectedStartDate = $("#StartDate").datepicker("getDate");
  selectedEndDate = $("#EndDate").datepicker("getDate");
  if (selectedStartDate != null && selectedEndDate != null) {
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(selectedEndDate.getTime() - selectedStartDate.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    alert(diffDays);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />Start:
<input type="text" id="StartDate" />End:
<input type="text" id="EndDate" />
```

Hope this help.